# How to filter dataset by regular expressions

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I need to filter rows (ticker,name) from dataset below, and do this like:

For example, search for pattern "AM" and it will give me "AMZN" ticker and "Bank of America Corporation".

My dataframe:

```
         ticker                         name
0          AAPL                   Apple Inc.
1           BAC  Bank of America Corporation
2          AMZN             Amazon.com, Inc.
3             T                    AT&T Inc.
4          GOOG                Alphabet Inc.
...         ...                          ...
106522  XHV-USD            HavenProtocol USD
106522  XHV-USD            HavenProtocol USD
106523  XNC-USD               XeniosCoin USD
106524  XVG-USD                    Verge USD
106525  ZEL-USD                  ZelCash USD
106526  ZNN-USD                    Zenon USD
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'ticker': ['AAPL', 'BAC', 'AMZN', 'T', 'GOOG', 'XHV-USD', 'XNC-USD', 'XVG-USD', 'ZEL-USD', 'ZNN-USD'],
                    'name': ['Apple Inc.', 'Bank of America Corporation', 'Amazon.com, Inc.', 'AT&T Inc.', 'Alphabet Inc.', 'HavenProtocol USD', 'XeniosCoin USD', 'Verge USD', 'ZelCash USD', 'Zenon USD']})

print(df[df['ticker'].str.contains('AM', case=False) | df['name'].str.contains('AM',case=False)])
```